# cannot find symbol (path) in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-13

i tried to use java.nio.file package ,but when i use Path class using intellij,i got this error:

```
can't find symbol (path)
```

code:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class IO_METHODS {

    public static void main(String args[]){

    Path target= Paths.get("mytext.txt");
    Path file= Files.createFile(target);



    }

}
```

why did i get this error ?

Comment: maybe because you didnt import `java.nio.file.Path`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't import `Path` . Do

```
import java.nio.file.Path
//...rest of imports and code
```

Comment: thanks,i though it's part of Paths class.
last thing,i got this error after i imported Path class:
Error:(16, 32) java: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: @mohamedamin in main do `public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{` and also import `java.io.*`

Comment: 2022 Not working Anymore